# handling large list of java objects in play framework

Tags: java, playframework

I trying to retrieve more than 255 objects in the list and have error `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I have added `@initbinder` but it doesn't work :

```java
@Value("${myApplication.autoGrowCollectionLimit:600}")
private int autoGrowCollectionLimit;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
      dataBinder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(autoGrowCollectionLimit);
}
```

View :

```html
 <tbody>
                                                                                    @if(vm.getPharmacyLogs != null && !vm.getPharmacyLogs.isEmpty){
                                                                                        @for((log,index) <- vm.getPharmacyLogs.zipWithIndex){

                                                                                    <tr discountValue="@log.getDiscountValue">
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <div class="dtlabel">No. Transaksi : </div>
                                                                                                    <div class="dtvalue">@log.getTransaction.getOrderNo</div>
                                                                                                    <div class="dtlabel m-t-5">Tgl/Jam : </div>
                                                                                                    <div class="dtvalue">@log.getTransaction.getCreatedDate @log.getTransaction.getCreatedTime</div>
                                                                                                </td>
```

Controller :

```java
public Result paymentPOST()throws RepoErrMessage.RepoException, NoSuchMethodException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{

        Form<ReceiveMstVM> form = formFactory.form(ReceiveMstVM.class);
        form = form.bindFromRequest();
        ReceiveMstVM vm = form.get();
```

Model :

```java
private List<TransactionLogisticVM> pharmacyLogs = new ArrayList<>();
```

How to increase limit size of List at Play Framework?

Comment: Please show the list code and how you are attempting to get items from it.

Comment: ok it's been added

Comment: Why all those tags? Scala? Spring? Akka?

Comment: java play framework